Steady-state approximation for thermal cracking
I was shown an application of the steady-state approximation to a thermal cracking reaction, which I think is not correct. The reaction is the thermal cracking of ethane: $\ce {C_2H_6 \rightarrow C_2H_4 + H_2}$ and the mechanism given was:
$\ce {C_2H_6 \xrightarrow{k_1} 2CH_3 \cdot}$ (Initiation, with rate $r_1$)
$\ce {CH_3 \cdot + C_2H_6 \xrightarrow{k_2} CH_4 + C_2H_5 \cdot}$ (Propagation, with rate $r_2$)
$\ce {C_2H_5 \xrightarrow{k_3} H \cdot + C_2H_4}$ (Propagation, with rate $r_3$)
$\ce {H \cdot + C_2H_6 \xrightarrow{k_4} H_2 + C_2H_5 \cdot}$ (Propagation, with rate $r_4$)
$\ce {CH_3 \cdot + H \cdot \xrightarrow{k_5} CH_4}$ (Termination, with rate $r_5$)
Now, the solution given was highly questionable as it equated the the rate of the 1st propagation step to that of the 3rd propagation step: $\ce {k_2 [CH_3 \cdot] [C_2H_6] = k_4 [C_2H_6] [H \cdot]}$. The professor further claims that the overall rate of the reaction is given by $\ce {r_4 = k_4 [C_2H_6] [H \cdot]}$. Note that the rate of initiation and the rate of termination are equal, i.e. $r_1 = r_5$, so we have $\ce {k_1 [C_2H_6] = k_5[CH_3 \cdot] [ H \cdot]}$. Combining and substituting, we obtain $\ce {r_4 = k_4\sqrt{\frac{k_1k_2}{k_4k_5}} [C_2H_6]^{3/2}}$.
If we apply SSA in the usual way: Letting $\ce {\frac{d[CH_3 \cdot]}{dt} = 0}$, we get $2r_1 = r_2 + r_5$. Letting $\ce {\frac{d[H \cdot]}{dt} = 0}$, we get $r_4 + r_5 = r_3$. Letting $\ce {\frac{d[C_2H_5 \cdot]}{dt} = 0}$, we get $r_2 + r_4 = r_3$. It is easy to see that $r_2 = r_5$, so $\ce {k_2 [CH_3 \cdot] [C_2H_6] = k_5 [CH_3 \cdot] [H \cdot]}$. This allows us to write $\ce {k_2 [C_2H_6] = k_5[H \cdot]}$. Finally, we obtain $\ce {r_4 = \frac{k_2 k_4}{k_5} [C_2H_6]^2}$.
Clearly, the two approaches yield different rate laws. I have two questions: Firstly, why can we claim that the overall rate is the rate of the 3rd propagation step, $r_4$? Secondly, whose SSA is correct? Mine or the lecturer's?

@Poutnik Ok I've edited
